# Dynamic switch statement: Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, switch-statement

I have an array of categories:

```
["main", "category1", "category2", "category3"]
```

I currently do the following to set the url for each list item when selected.

```
- (void)selectionList:(HTHorizontalSelectionList *)selectionList didSelectButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index{

    NSString *subCategoryURL = @"";
    tapCellIndex = -1;

    switch (index) {
        case 1: {
            subCategoryURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/",CATEGORYURL,@"category1"];
        }
            break;
        case 2: {
            subCategoryURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/",CATEGORYURL,@"category2"];
        }
            break;
        case 3: {
            subCategoryURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/",CATEGORYURL,@"category3"];
        }
            break;
        case 0: {
            isMenuChoosed = NO;
            [self getHomePageDetails];
            return;
        }
            break;
        default: {
            subCategoryURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/",CATEGORYURL,@"category1"];
        }
            break;
    }
    CategoryURL = subCategoryURL;
    [self getCategoryDeatils:subCategoryURL];
}
```

This works as is. However, my categories may change position in the list, and new categories may be added or removed, so I need the switch statement to be dynamic.

For example, the number of cases needs to be the amount of items in the array and the `categoryX` (ending in url) needs to be the name of the category in the array.

Could someone help me do this please?

Comment: "For example, the number of cases needs to be the amount of items in the array" Then you can't use a `switch` statement. The `switch` statement needs to be completely written out at compile time, but you won't know the number of categories until runtime.

Comment: @matt Is there another solution then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allCategories = @["main", "category1", "category2", "category3"]
```

if you create the buttons according to this array then you can do

```
    - (void)selectionList:(HTHorizontalSelectionList *)selectionList didSelectButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index{

        NSString *subCategoryURL = @"";
        if(![allCategories[index] isEqualToString:@"main"])
        {
             subCategoryURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/",CATEGORYURL,allCategories[index]];
        }
        else
        {
             //main here
             return;
        }

    CategoryURL = subCategoryURL;
    [self getCategoryDeatils:subCategoryURL];
}
```